# `console.log(responseText);` and `console.log(file);` not displaying any data

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I am using following configuration for dropzone.
My problem is that files are uploading in server but   `console.log(response);` and `console.log(file);` are not displaying any content in console.
Also remove link is not added to picture.

```
<form action="UploadImages"
      class="dropzone"
      id="image-uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <i class="fa fa-image" id="dzopen"></i>
</form>                
<div id="media-upload-previews">
</div>
 Dropzone.options.dz = {
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        url: 'UploadImages',
        previewsContainer: "#media-upload-previews",
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 5,
        maxFiles: 20,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*,audio/*,video/*",
        init: function() {
            this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                var response = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText);
                alert(file);
                alert(responseText);
              });
            this.on("thumbnail", function(file, dataUrl) {
                $('.select_img').html('<img src="' + dataUrl + '" width="50" height="50" alt="">');
            });
            this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
            });
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** Here I want to show image with with and height of 50 (insted of default preview) and after uploading I want to show `file, responseText` value in console so that i can use it for delete.
But this is not showing inage with specified width and height and after upload not giving response to console how to do these

Comment: You checking console.log() in which browser ? On IE it will not work , check on Chrome / Mozilla. I hope this can help you little.

Comment: I am using Google Crome Version 39.0.2171.71 m

Comment: why dont you try on "complete" instead of on "success" ?

Comment: tryed `this.on("complete", function(file) {
                alert(file);
            });` not showing anything

Comment: @xrcwrn: `alert` works?

Comment: Can you provide an url? Can you confirm, that your server sends feedback? What happens if you reduce your code to: $(function() {Dropzone.options.dz = {success: function(file, response){alert(response);}};});

Comment: Yes I tried here now working `http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/y8697re4/4/`

Comment: @haywire getting response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried this working properly http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/y8697re4/4/

```
$("i#dzopen").dropzone({
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 10,
    url: 'UploadImages',
    previewsContainer: "#media-upload-previews",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 20,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*,audio/*,video/*",
    init: function () {
        this.on("success", function (file, responseText) {
            alert(file);
            alert(responseText);
           console.log(file);
        });
        this.on("thumbnail", function (file, dataUrl) {
            $('#media-upload-previews').append('<img src="' + dataUrl + '" width="50" height="50" alt="">');
        });
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {});
        this.on("complete", function (file) {
            alert(file);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Accept this answer if you solved your problem so the question doesn't stay unsolved.